# How to animate/park a top down car with GSAP

Tags: animation, gsap

I'm just trying some things with the GSAP libraries TweenMax and TimelineMax.

What I want to accomplish is a car parking top down in an angle of 90 degrees. But I'm not sure what kind of math is needed for this to make it look authentic.

I've got this Fiddle in which I try a turn, but it looks more like the car is drifting.

Any suggestions?

```
timeline.to(car, 2, {
            x: "-=300", y: "+=300", ease: Linear.easeNone
        }).to(car, 0.25, {
            x: "-=30", y: "+=50", directionalRotation: "-=5_ccw", ease: Linear.easeNone
        }).to(car, 0.25, {
            x: "-=30", y: "+=50", directionalRotation: "-=5_ccw", ease: Linear.easeNone
        }).to(car, 0.25, {
            x: "-=30", y: "+=50", directionalRotation: "-=5_ccw", ease: Linear.easeNone
        }).to(car, 0.25, {
            x: "-=30", y: "+=50", directionalRotation: "-=5_ccw", ease: Linear.easeNone
        }).to(car, 0.25, {
            x: "-=30", y: "+=50", directionalRotation: "-=5_ccw", ease: Linear.easeNone
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle isn't linked.

GSAP's TweenMax contains a Bezier Plugin which allows objects to move along a path, which is what you want, rather than discreet values, which is what you have.

```
TweenMax.to(car, 2, {bezier:{values:path, type:"cubic"}, ease:Linear.easeNone})
```

[Documentation](https://greensock.com/docs/Plugins/BezierPlugin)

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VerMWX)

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nqk27f1/4/)
Yes, I tried that, but with the bezier function, I'm having trouble using the autoRotate. The car needs to be facing the same way the whole time. I gave up using the bezier so I could use directionalRotation.

Comment: I see what you mean about the drifting. It looks like you're really close. Is the problem not in fact that the car is facing the same way the whole time? If it rotated slightly towards the direction it was heading then it would not look like it was skidding/drifting. When you park a car in real life the direction certainly changes.

Comment: Yeah, so I have either [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nqk27f1/1/), where I can control the direction myself, but where the animation is not smooth. Or [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nqk27f1/4), where the animation is smooth, but I cannot control the direction the car is going in. I actually need something in between.

Comment: aha I see. So you're fiddle with the bezier curve is very close. You had the autoRotate property in the wrong place. Also, it can take more arguments to get the control right. See my updated version https://jsfiddle.net/1nqk27f1/5/ the '0' in the array is the number of additional degrees to normal (can be +/-) so experimenting with that should get you there. I can't quite tell where the car is trying to park, so hard to get it right myself.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can figure it out now